# App Tracking Transparency implementation with firebase/facebook analytics

Tags: ios, flutter, firebase-analytics, apptrackingtransparency

Since ios 14 developers are required to use [App Tracking Transparency framework](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/apptrackingtransparency) to request permissions from user for tracking.

My app is running in flutter and uses firebase analytics and facebook analytics to log custom events for example: `logFirebaseEvent("registration_complete", data: {...})`.

Now when I have requested permission from the user for tracking or he denied it do I have to manually handle this logic in my app or is this handled by the apple system under the hood?

I havent found any more information other than that I should include the dialog.